# How can I make buffer with ST_Buffer in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, buffer, syntax

I am trying to make a buffer(0) as a fix-geometry process in PostGIS 2.2.2. 
It like this:

> SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),0,4);

I am using sources from [this](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) man-page. It creates an output that goes like this:

```
  ----------------------
  010300000000000000000
  (1 row)
```

But I am not sure if I am actually just simulating the creation of a buffer in PostGIS or I am actually making a buffer on database#scheme.table

What I would like to is to make an ST_Buffer of all the geometries (polygon) in the table. Seems like getting something wrong. The syntax is foreign to me though.

I have experienced that it isn't like: ST_Buffer(scheme.table, 0) but how am I to understand [these](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) examples?

Comment: Further I've tried to query it this way: `SELECT ST_Buffer('scheme.table', 0);`
Which outputs: _ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
HINT: "im" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
CONTEXT: SQL function "st_buffer" statement 1_

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. Are you trying to select a "buffered" version of your geometries or are you trying to change the geometries to the "buffered" version?

Comment: None of the above. I am trying to make a buffer on the geometries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is:

```
SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry_column, 0) FROM scheme.table
```

Where geometry_column is the column within your table (scheme.table) that contains your geometry.

You current result of:

```
  ----------------------
  010300000000000000000
  (1 row)
```

Looks correct, that is the well known binary version of the geometry, or how PostgreSQL sees it. For human readable try:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'),0,4));
```

Result:

```
POLYGON EMPTY
```

Obviously a 0 unit buffer of a point will result in an empty polygon.

While that is one way to fix geometries. A better solution would be [ST_MakeValid](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_MakeValid.html).

Comment: `SELECT ST_Buffer(geometry_column, 0) FROM scheme.table;` prints out the statement that: _ERROR: function st_buffer(integer, integer) does not exist_ 
I am running PostGIS 2.2.2 so this could not be the explanation. 

I am aware of ST_MakeValid, what I had been reading though was that it wouldn't be clear what it exactly did in the process. Besides then I see ST_Buffer as a way of actually learning the syntax and the query-methods on PostgreSQL/PostGIS. If I cannot make ST_Buffer work, i probably wont have any luck with any other ST_* commands.

Comment: That error suggests that your geometry_column is not of type geometry. Can you post your create table statement, and possibly a couple of sample records?

Comment: When I started with PostGIS I used the Boundless tutorial: http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/ I would heavily recommend running through the full intro to get a basic grasp of how PostGIS works. Run through at least exercises 1-21. 21 will answer most of your questions about validity as well.

Comment: @mlinth it is a table created from an imported shapefile. 
I have created an instance in qGIS desktop to PostGIS and I am able to import the table and have geometries shown visualized.

Comment: You have PGAdmin, right? Navigate through the tree in the "object browser" (database server, database, schema...) and click on the table. In the "SQL Pane" in the bottom half of the right-hand side of the screen you should see see some SQL beginning "CREATE TABLE". Copy that and add it to your question. That way we know the names and types of all your columns and can help you better...

Comment: @mlinth
`import.imp_tabl_spmgnt100all_netto
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  mslink double precision,
  rumnr character varying(50),
  rumnavn character varying(50),
  airside double precision,
  pass_adg double precision,
  lokalekat character varying(50),
  areal double precision,
  ltc_cat character varying(50),
  kontraktnr character varying(50),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon), `

Comment: Interesting is that in qGIS, with a PostGIS-connection to the database. I see two tables. One with Features, and one without. 
In pgAdmin III, i only see one, with features.

Comment: So run: SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 0) FROM import.imp_tabl_spmgnt100all_netto

Comment: @Vesanto I receive this output: _First argument geometry could not be converted to GEOS: IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring_ 
I would guess that the ST_Buffer function cannot get pass the issue that I try to make it solve.

Comment: Try: SELECT ST_Buffer(geom, 10) FROM import.imp_tabl_spmgnt100all_netto

Comment: @Vesanto
- Same error output

Comment: Try: SELECT ST_IsValidReason(geom) FROM import.imp_tabl_spmgnt100all_netto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42124/discussion-between-vesanto-and-michael).

Comment: @Vesanto What it outputs are basically either: _Self-intersection[-67864.6 133936.005]_ or _IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring_